# Build gradle firebase error for flutter/dart

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, dart

apparently i faced this problem when updating the firebase package version in pubspec yaml and I've looked up to similar problems and referred to the suggestions online but to no avail. Can anyone help with this?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\User\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 362
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_auth_web'.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1